# Upgrading Jackson in GlassFish 4.1

Tags: java, glassfish, jackson, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1

I am using GlassFish 4.1, which includes Jackson 2.3.2.

I would like to upgrade to the newest version of Jackson (currently 2.4.4).

Is the procedure for upgrading Jackson in GlassFish 4.1 as simple as:

a) stopping GlassFish

b) deleting the osgi-cache

c) replacing the Jackson 2.3.2 jars in the glassfish/modules directory with newer versions

d) starting GlassFish

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Please @see https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21141

The procedure I followed was

- asadmin stop-domain delete felix cache
- $rm -rf domains/domain1/osgi-cache/felix/
- copy jackson-*-2.4.2.jars as
  modules/jackson-*.jar
- asadmin start-domain

Comment: Currently, I using Spring Framework 4.x and I do not want to override jackson file in glassfish. 
What is other solution to run? Ex: add dependency in pom.xml.