# Exclude methods of jax-rs service from swagger.json

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, glassfish-4, nosuchmethoderror

I´m using swagger on my java EE7 application (Glassfish as application server). Everything works fine except for a method with FormDataParam, which gave me the tradicional error:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

I tried everything, but is just a method, so I do not want so badly this method in my swagger.json

How can I exclude this method from swagger. I tried:

```
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true) and @ApiOperation(value="",hidden = true)
@POST
@Path("something")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response newsomething(@FormParam("something") String something,@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    return "something";
}
```

What I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related with Glassfish, it use different version of Jackson. You need to upgrade Glassfish/Jackson. More details:

- `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Integer` solution  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1001
- [Upgrading Jackson in GlassFish 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334528/upgrading-jackson-in-glassfish-4-1)
- [com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector not found --- while using Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538801/com-fasterxml-jackson-module-jaxb-jaxbannotationintrospector-not-found-while?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Integer;` solution - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/uQEn-anX_Og
- `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyDesc` solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/x-Pz_3orTCE

Comment: Upgrading Jackson in GlassFish 4.1 was the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

For me adding  @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true) in paths worked
Is it wrong or correct?

```
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@ApiOperation(value = "return getApi ",
        tags = {"getApi"},
        notes = "Returns a Array of getApi",
        hidden = true
        )
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(response = GetApi.class, message = "", code = 200)
})
@Path("getApi")
public Response getApi(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @BeanParam QueryParamBean queryParamBean) {
             // codes..
}
```